# UIViewController in UINavigationController does not rotate as expected

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, autorotate

I have a UINavigationController who's root UIViewController only supports Portrait orientation. When the user presses a button a second UIViewController gets loaded and pushed onto the stack, this view controller, let's call it secondViewController, only supports landscape orientation.

Usually what would happen is that the interface rotates during the transition to secondViewController, but this doesn't happen despite shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: getting called on secondViewController. Once I tilt the device manually when secondViewController is displayed it rotates as expected and when switching back to the first UIViewController it rotates back to portrait as it should.

To test whether the allowed interface Orientations of the first UIViewController have any influence on the process I set a return YES; for all the interfaces there, however, the problem persisted. I also read the [technical Q&A on the subject](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html) but according to this doc everything should be fine, the UINavigationController is the only subview of the window.

I create secondViewController completely programmatically (overwriting of loadView) and had this particular case working before in other apps. Does anybody have an idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the change doesn't happen automatically, the following gives the neccessary "push":

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
}
```